# Does using column-major matrices in OpenGL cause striding on the GPU?

Tags: opengl, gpu, linear-algebra

OpenGL conventionally (in documentation, examples etc.) uses column-major matrices and column vectors.  Since a matrix-vector transform involves the dot product of the matrix rows with the column vector, does the GPU suffer striding and loss of spatial locality?  Does the GPU re-arrange the 4x4 matrices between the GLSL and the GPU assembly code to remedy this?

It seems like it would make the dot-products faster to grab the first four floats of the matrix if they were laid out in rows, such that the GPU only has to make one memory access instead of four.

Comment: It seems like Cg used to allow choosing a matrix layout on the GPU, but that isn't possible on OpenGL, is it? http://www.tilander.org/aurora2/Matrices_are_from_Venus/index.html

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL uses column-major **notation**, but that is merely a **notation**. The underlying storage format is as you would expect.

The following matrix in column-major notation:

```
xx yx zx wx
xy yy zy wy
xz yz zz wz
0  0  0  1
```

is stored in memory like this:

```
xx xy xz 0 yx yy yz 0 zx zy zz 0 wx wy wz 1
```

Which, when executing a `Matrix * vector` product, can indeed be fetched in 4 perfectly coalesced accesses of 16 bytes each.

[From the docs:](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm)

> **9.005 Are OpenGL matrices column-major or row-major?**
>
> For programming purposes, OpenGL matrices are 16-value arrays with
>   base vectors laid out contiguously in memory. The translation
>   components occupy the 13th, 14th, and 15th elements of the 16-element
>   matrix, where indices are numbered from 1 to 16 as described in
>   section 2.11.2 of the OpenGL 2.1 Specification.
>
> Column-major versus row-major is purely a notational convention. Note
>   that post-multiplying with column-major matrices produces the same
>   result as pre-multiplying with row-major matrices. The OpenGL
>   Specification and the OpenGL Reference Manual both use column-major
>   notation. You can use any notation, as long as it's clearly stated.
>
> Sadly, the use of column-major format in the spec and blue book has
>   resulted in endless confusion in the OpenGL programming community.
>   Column-major notation suggests that matrices are not laid out in
>   memory as a programmer would expect.

Comment: Ack, I have read that FAQ a million times but never seized on BASE VECTORS being contiguously laid out in memory.  Although, wouldn't the dot product be grabbing xx yx zx wx?

Comment: @MaiLongdong: At least on the client side the memory layout is column major and not what you depicted. Also most GPUs have it that way. However this usually doesn't cause a problem, as GPU's memory fetch and cache circuitry have been designed with that in mind.

Comment: @MaiLongdong: Base Vectors are column vectors in OpenGL notation. If you look at a (regular) modelview matrix, it's first column is the X, the second is the Y and the third the Z vector of the model space transformed to view. In fact if you take the third vector (Z) it tells you the direction the "camera" is looking at. Also the translation vector of the transformation matrix is the fourth column, which occupies the 13th, 14th and 15th elements.

Comment: Oh, yes, my matrix above should be transposed indeed. Fixed, thank you.